# Is there a way to ping a Bluetooth device from Windows?

Tags: bluetooth, ping, autoit

I am trying to automate [CCTV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-circuit_television) arming on Windows 10 using AutoIt - trying to arm the camera when I am not at home by pinging my phone ([Samsung Galaxy S7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S7)).

I tried pinging the phone's local IP address, but when it goes to sleep, it stops pinging. I have seen some posts about pinging the Bluetooth address, but I can't find any actual instructions... How can I do it?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to "ping" your phone? To get it out of "sleep"?

Comment: Yes and no. Depends on what kind of "ping" you need exactly. Any way, it is complex task.

Comment: I need to ping the phone for the cctv software to see if I'm in (get a response so keep motion detection off) or out (ping get no response so turn motion detection on). I use contacam for cctv and autoit for automation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use DllCall() and the Windows API:
[Bluetooth](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_bluetooth/)
and [Bluetooth Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bluetooth/bluetooth-reference). And take a look here:

To these examples:

```autoit
#include <WinAPI.au3>

;~ https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/140162-help-with-dllstruct-and-pointers/?tab=comments#comment-984341

Global Const $hDllBthProps = DllOpen("bthprops.cpl")

Global $phRadio
Global $hFind = _BluetoothFindFirstRadio($phRadio)
MsgBox(0, "", "error: " & @error & @CRLF & "hFind: " & $hFind & @CRLF & "hRadio: " & $phRadio)
_WinAPI_CloseHandle($phRadio)
_BluetoothFindRadioClose($hFind)

Func _BluetoothFindFirstRadio(ByRef $phRadio)
    Local $tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS = DllStructCreate('DWORD')
    DllStructSetData($tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS, 1, DllStructGetSize($tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS))
    Local $aResult = DllCall($hDllBthProps, "handle", "BluetoothFindFirstRadio", "struct*", $tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS, "handle*", 0)
    If @error Then Return SetError(2, @error, 0)
    $phRadio = $aResult[2]
    Return SetError($aResult[0] = 0, 0, $aResult[0])
EndFunc   ;==>_BluetoothFindFirstRadio

Func _BluetoothFindRadioClose($hBtFind)
    Local $aResult = DllCall($hDllBthProps, "bool", "BluetoothFindRadioClose", "handle", $hBtFind)
    If @error Then Return SetError(2, @error, 0)
    Return SetError($aResult[0] = 0, 0, $aResult[0])
EndFunc   ;==>_BluetoothFindRadioClose
```